# Getting error in fetching image URL from firebase android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to get the Url of Compressed image using firebase but it gives me the task detail not giving image Url But getting only Task details

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-hj-lIj0PM&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcQ3o2jmZtwu2wXEA4OIIq53&index=16
https://github.com/akrajilwar/Android-Image-Upload/tree/master/app/src

```
     filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();
                           Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                           final String URI = downloadUrl.toString();
                           Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,URI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                    String thumb_downloadUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(thumb_task.getResult()).getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                    if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                        Map<String, Object> update_hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                        update_hashMap.put("image", URI);
                                        update_hashMap.put("thumbimage", thumb_downloadUrl);

                                        databaseReference.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                }

                                            }
                                        });



                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading thumbnail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                    }


                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                }


            });
```

i want to get ("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nextsapp-dcc76.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FDsxy1aYjrgNZJDm6JfmEjrbbdsi2.jpg?alt=media&token=d571b2c5-7ebc-4704-b4e3-81b4275de121") like Url
 but getting task Details like("com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@6594ce7")

Comment: You should straight away upload the URI instead.

Comment: check this https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/how-do-i-upload-image-to-firebase-and-retrieve-it-using-picasso.972573/#post-5167043